# How to correctly compare years within MM-dd-yyyy strings?

Tags: javascript, dhtmlx, datejs

I'm using date.js to apply conditional formatting to a data grid. The data is parsed from a javascript array. All of my conditions are working correctly, except for this one:

if (val < today && val > '01-01-2000')

val is a string in MM-dd-yyyy format that I can't change. So I used date.js to convert today's date to a string in MM-dd-yyyy format and make the comparison. The problem is that 01-17-2014 is seen as less than 04-08-2013 - since it is comparing strings.

What's the best way around this?

I'd like to make it simple, which is why I converted to strings in the first place, but I'm not sure how to get around the year issue.

Thanks for any help!

```
var today = new Date.today().toString("MM-dd-yyyy");
var tomorrow = new Date.today().addDays(1).toString("MM-dd-yyyy");
var upcoming = new Date.today().addDays(7).toString("MM-dd-yyyy");

function eXcell_edncl(cell) {
    this.base = eXcell_edn;
    this.base(cell);
    this.setValue = function(val) {
        if (val.indexOf('ACT') >= 0) this.cell.style.backgroundColor="lightgreen";
        else if (val.indexOf('PV') >= 0) this.cell.style.backgroundColor="lightgreen", this.cell.style.fontSize="20px";
        else if (val.indexOf('YES') >= 0) this.cell.style.backgroundColor="lightgreen", this.cell.style.fontSize="20px";
        else if (val < today && val > '01-01-2000') this.cell.style.backgroundColor="red";
        else if (val == today) this.cell.style.backgroundColor="orange";
        else if (val == tomorrow) this.cell.style.backgroundColor="yellow";
        else if (val > tomorrow && val <= upcoming) this.cell.style.backgroundColor="lightyellow";
        else this.cell.style.backgroundColor="";
        this.cell.innerHTML = this.grid._aplNF(val, this.cell._cellIndex);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The best way around this issue is to not convert your Date objects into Strings. `"01-17-2014" < "04-08-2013"`evaluates to true because `"01" < "04"` is true, so whatever is tacked onto those strings will always evaluate the same way. However, using the less than/greater than operators on Date objects will behave as expected. So you can modify your existing if statement to be

```
if (new Date(val) < new Date(today) && new Date(val) > new Date('01-01-2000'))
```

and that will resolve your problem, but you are probably better off using the Date objects to begin with.

Comment: Thanks. That makes sense. I tried:
else if (new Date(val) < new Date(today) && new Date(val) > new Date('01-01-2000')) this.cell.style.backgroundColor="red";
But it isn't turning dates that are indeed less then today to a red background.

Comment: Comparing `Date` instances like this works because the [relational operators `<` and `>`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.8.1) implicitly call the instance's `valueOf()` method (which is inherited from `Date.prototype`), through the internal `ToPrimitive` algorithm, which returns the instance's time value (the same as `getTime()`) . It can work for any other object that has or inherits such a method.

Comment: @user1911141 `new Date('01-01-2000')` does _not_ result in a `Date` instance for January 1, 2000. You want to [RTFM on supported date formats](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date), or write `new Date(2000, 0, 1)` to be sure (yes, the month is 0-based).

Comment: Tried new Date(2000, 0, 1) but it still isn't recognizing the condition for dates earlier than today. TFTFH though.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using date.js you can use its compare function, as described on the [documentation](https://code.google.com/p/datejs/wiki/APIDocumentation):

> Date.compare ( Date date1, Date date2 ) : Number
>
> Compares the first date to the second date and returns an number indication of their relative values. -1 = this is lessthan date. 0 = values are equal. 1 = this is greaterthan date.

See the documentation for a code example.

Answer (score 1):

You may not be able to change the format of the date string in the UI, but it should not matter what format it is in in the back-end. You should change the code to use [ISO 8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) which was designed to allow easy comparison in string format (among other advantages).

The format of your dates would then be `yyyy-MM-dd` which would allow you to compare them as strings.

And because it is relevant, check out [this XKCD comic](http://xkcd.com/1179/) if you are still on the fence.

Comment: Thanks Jesse. This makes the most sense to me, but I'm not sure how to convert my val string from MM-dd-yyyy to yyyy-MM-dd. I tried:
var val2 = new Date.val.toString("yyyy-MM-dd");
and
var val2 = new Date(val).toString("yyyy-MM-dd");
but neither did the trick. Can you help me with that part?

Comment: @user1911141 I am no expert in JavaScript and especially not with Dates in JavaScript. But [this StackOverflow Q&A](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1056728/formatting-a-date-in-javascript) might help you out. If you still are having problems, feel free to create a new question about your specific problem and the right people will try to help you out.

Answer (score 0):

Ended up with the following working. Needed to parse the values coming in:

```
var today = new Date.today().toString("MM-dd-yyyy");
var today2 = new Date.today();
var old = new Date(2000, 0, 1);
var tomorrow = new Date.today().addDays(1).toString("MM-dd-yyyy");
var upcoming = new Date.today().addDays(7).toString("MM-dd-yyyy");

function eXcell_edncl(cell) {
    this.base = eXcell_edn;
    this.base(cell);
    this.setValue = function(val) {
        var val2 = new Date.parse(val);
        if (val.indexOf('ACT') >= 0) this.cell.style.backgroundColor="lightgreen";
        else if (val.indexOf('PV') >= 0) this.cell.style.backgroundColor="lightgreen", this.cell.style.fontSize="20px";
        else if (val.indexOf('YES') >= 0) this.cell.style.backgroundColor="lightgreen", this.cell.style.fontSize="20px";
        else if (val2 < today2 && val2 > old) this.cell.style.backgroundColor="red";
        else if (val == today) this.cell.style.backgroundColor="orange";
        else if (val == tomorrow) this.cell.style.backgroundColor="yellow";
        else if (val > tomorrow && val <= upcoming) this.cell.style.backgroundColor="lightyellow";
        else this.cell.style.backgroundColor="";
        this.cell.innerHTML = this.grid._aplNF(val, this.cell._cellIndex);
    }
}
```

Comment: As default said, your "best" option is to work with date objects and only convert to strings for output.